# python script to connect to aws s3 bucket and command multiple json documents into one json documents using aws cli

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an application which drops multiple json documents onto an aws s3 bucket and I'll have to consume this data by merging all these json documents into one single large file to make it available for other downstream applications. I'm using aws cli and calling a python script to accomplish the same. But, the code below is not consolidating all of the data into one single file.

***Python:***

```
import boto3
import json

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def conjsondocuments(bucket, prefix, output_file):
    result = []

    response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
    json_file_keys = [obj['Key'] for obj in response.get('Contents', [])]

    for key in json_file_keys:
        data = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        content = data['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")

        if content:
            try:
                content_json = json.loads(content)
                result.extend(content_json)
                #print(content_json) content_json has data
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                print(f"Error decoding JSON from {key}: {e}")
        else:
            print(f"Empty content from {key}")

    with open(output_file, 'w') as output:
        json.dump(result, output, indent=2)

    print(f"Consolidated JSON document has been saved to the path: {prefix}{output_file}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bucket_name = 'myawss3'
    prefix_path = '/myfolder/myfile/'
    output_json_file = 'conjsondoc.json'

    conjsondocuments(bucket_name, prefix_path, output_json_file)
```

I need to combine all the JSON documents in the directory into one single large file but unable to accomplish, `result.extend` is not working as expected.

Comment: " the code below is not consolidating" - its not clear. What exactly is happening? Any errors, unexpected outputs, ...?

Comment: No errors or any unexpected output.

Comment: So what's wrong exactly?